# I have a test functionality that need to test with multiple users, so it need multiple contexts, how to record a single video using playwright

Tags: playwright

I have a test functionality that need to test with multiple users in a single test, I achieved this using multiple contexts in playwright.

I see, we can record the video if we are using a single context.

Are there ways in playwright to perform below actions?

1. record a single video in playwright in a test, while using multiple context
   ex: admin = browser.newContext()
   user = browser.newContext()
2. Can we change the cookies in the Session storage or entire SessionStorage data in the existing context at runtime and reload the page, I think this way also i have option to change the current user.

Comment: Please try to choose a better title for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to record a single video in Playwright while using multiple contexts. You can do this by setting the recordVideo option in the browser context options. For example:

```
const adminContext = await browser.newContext({
  recordVideo: {
    dir: 'videos/',
  },
});
const userContext = await browser.newContext({
  recordVideo: {
    dir: 'videos/',
  },
});
```

This will create two separate videos, one for the admin context and one for the user context. The videos will be saved in the videos/ directory.

To change the cookies in the SessionStorage or entire SessionStorage data in the existing context at runtime, you can use the page.setCookie() or page.clearCookies() methods. For example:

```
const adminPage = await adminContext.newPage();
await adminPage.setCookie('username', 'admin');
await adminPage.goto('https://example.com');

const userPage = await userContext.newPage();
await userPage.setCookie('username', 'user');
await userPage.goto('https://example.com');
```

This will set the username cookie to admin for the admin context and user for the user context. The cookies will be stored in the SessionStorage for each context.

Once you have changed the cookies, you can reload the page to see the changes.

Comment: Thank you, the first  solution will not work for me, as it creates 2 videos 

 but with context cookies, i can reset it and set new cookie and reload the page, this works